# Definition of C# data structures and algorithms

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

This may be a silly question (with MSDN and all), but maybe some of you will be able to help me sift through amazing amounts of information.

I need to know the specifics of the implementations of common data structures and algorithms in C#. That is, for example, I need to know, say, how Linked Lists are handled and represented, how they and their methods are defined.

Is there a good centralized source of documentation for this (with code), or should I just reconstruct it? Have you ever had to know the specifics of these things to decide what to use?

Regards, and thanks.

Comment: How much time do you have before the interview?

Comment: Haaaaaaaaahahahaha. I don't do interviews. I'm a poor compsci prof. Just doing some research and this has become critical. But that made me laugh.

Comment: Oops. I'm sorry I unknowingly recommended CLRS to a CS Prof!

Comment: Don't worry, he did say "poor", so maybe he hasn't been able to afford it yet ;)

Comment: No need to buy everything. Many of us just read these books from the library, no need to own to know. :)

Comment: ... and don't forget piracy ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scott Mitchell has a great 6-part article that covers many .NET data structures:

[An Extensive Examination of Data Structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287104(VS.71).aspx)

For an algorithmic overview of data structures, I suggest reading *the* algorithm textbook: "Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen, et al..

For details on each .NET data structure the MSDN page on that specific class is good.

When all of them fail to address issues, [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) is always there. You can use it to dig through the actual source and see things for yourself.

Comment: Great answer, Mehrdad. Thanks. And thanks also for the clarification on my comment to samoz.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to learn it, try making your own.

Googling for linked lists will give you a lot of hits and sample code to go off of. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) will also be a good resource.

Comment: This is not a bad idea... but I was wondering maybe C# ahs optimizations I could never implement without really knowing, say, CLI or something like that, and I don't have time to go into too much detail.

Comment: @Dervin: I don't think collection classes have any specific optimization at the CIL level. However, internally, the runtime can treat some classes in special ways. For instance, I think `List<T>` actions are optimized by the runtime.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on the language.  Most languages have the very basics now pre-built with them, but that doesn't mean their implementations are the same.  The same named object--LinkedList in C# is completely different than the LinkedList in Java or C++.  Even the String library is different.  C# for instance is known to create a new String object every time you assign a string a new value...this becomes something you learn quickly when it brings your program to a crashing halt when you're working with substrings in C# for the first time.

So the answer to your question is massively complicated because I don't know quite what you're after.  If you're just going to be teaching a class what a generic version of these algorithms and data structures are, you can present them without getting into the problems I mentioned above.  You'll just need to select, lookup, read about a particular type of implementation of them.  Like for LinkedList you need to be able to instantiate the list, destroy the list, copy the list, add to the list somewhere (usually front/back), remove from the list, etc.  You could get fancy and add as many methods as you want.

Comment: Just FYI, the OP was specifically asking about C#'s implementations; wanting to see how they are coded.